# How to copy range of cells to last empty row on new worksheet at specific time of day

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post so all help would be greatly appreciated!

Basically what I am trying to do.. I would like a macro to copy a range of cells ("Summary" sheet) that hold dynamic data (RTD), to a new worksheet ("Capture data") at a specific time. Now, I am by no means a VBA expert but I do have some programming experience. I have had a fair look around on the internet too and below is what I have managed to salvage, but it does not copy all the cells in the range, it only copies the first cell.

This block of code is in the "ThisWorkbook" object, which is to run macro on time:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
dNextTime = TimeSerial(14, 30, 0)
dNextTime = Date + dNextTime + IIf(Now > (Date + dNextTime), 1, 0)
Application.OnTime dNextTime, "CaptureHeadlines"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime dNextTime, "CaptureHeadlines", Schedule:=False
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And the below block of code is in the "Module1" folder which is to copy the contents of the range of cells across to the new sheet:

```
Public dNextTime As Double

Sub CaptureHeadlines()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Summary")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Data capture")

copySheet.Range("B21:O37").Copy
pasteSheet.Range(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteAll

Application.CutCopyMode = False

dNextTime = dNextTime + 1
Application.OnTime dNextTime, "CaptureHeadlines"

End Sub
```

Again, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know anything about `OnTime` or `TimeSerial`, but you said your problem was with pasting data. If that is the case, try the following.

```
Sub CaptureHeadlines()

    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowPasteSheet As Long

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Summary")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Data capture")
    LastRowPasteSheet = pasteSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    copySheet.Range("B21:O37").Copy
    pasteSheet.Range("A" & LastRowPasteSheet).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```